# How to change a color of column in Twig

Tags: php, html, twig

I want change the color of column of table in `Twig`.
If the value of the column > 0 ==> color green
else ==> color red.

I tried to change it by `set color` but it doesn't work :

```
 <tr class="danger">

     <td>{{widget[loop.index]|raw}}</td>
     <td>{{widget[loop.index+1]|raw}}</td>
     <td>{{widget[loop.index+2]|raw}}</td>

        {% if (loop.index+3) > 0 %} 
            {% set color = red %}  

     <td>{{widget[loop.index+3]|raw}}</td>

        {%endif%}

  </tr>
```

How can I do it by `twig` or `HTML`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use that variable inside twig to show anything at all

```
{% set color = (loop.index+3) > 0 ? 'red' : 'green' %}  
<td style="background: {{ color }};">{{widget[loop.index+3]|raw}}</td>
```

(*do note `loop.index+3` is always greater than 0, surely you are looking for something more like, `{% set color = widget[loop.index+3] > 0 ? 'red' : 'green' %}`*)